# sending xmlhttprequest to javame securesocketserver

Tags: xmlhttprequest, java-me, connector, sslhandshakeexception

I've written a MIDlet server that handle tcp inputstream. I send xmlhttprequest with an http:// url from a html web page and it works fine. I want to do the same with an https url.

with my secureserverconnection instancied by a connector.open the accecptandopen() method return an exception.
[handshake client send](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWuXk.png)

As you can see the xmlhttprequest send an handshake hello but I've notices tls1.2 protocol then tls1.0 protocol and finally tls1.2.

Is it normal having 2 different protocol sent by the client. It is the first phase of the handshake protocol.
My Midlet java server respond with an Alert and a a "ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher" error (IOException)

[IOexception capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAqM0.png)

I've specified the connector options like this  :  cipher  : TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 and TLSv1.2 protocol

[tlsv1.2 server response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EGwR.png)

Have someone ever done it or can explain me why the cipher handshake is in error?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is normal for the client to try both protocols. The most likely scenario is that your device simply lacks any valid certificates, since J2ME devices are so old.

See:
["ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher" in server depending on server certificate and key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292951/ssl3-get-client-hellono-shared-cipher-in-server-depending-on-server-certifica)